# How To recreate bootloader to UEFI?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, bootloader

My hard drive is malfunctioning and not being recognized by my computer.  However, i can use testdisk and get to the data on the drive and copy it, so i know data is in tact.

I took it to a computer repair shop and they stated I needed to `recreate the bootloader to UEFI` - but wanted to charge me $500 for the task...i figured I have to be able to get steps on this from the internet so thought i'd ask here...

**EDIT**
This occured after I removed the drive and placed it into an external drive cloner and I tried to clone my 1TB to an 8TB drive using the `SSK Hard Disk Docking Station` - after doing this, I plugged my SSD Drive back into the original computer it came from and now it will only boot into the BIOS.  It never seems to recognize the drive.

This is for Windows 10

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Bootloader for which operating system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I assume your computer uses Windows.)

The sentence "recreate the bootloader to UEFI" probably stands for the
technical term of "Startup Repair", which means that your Windows
version lost its code that's used for booting and it needs renewing.
$500 is indeed very exaggerated for such a simple task.

The first action you should do is ensure that you have backups for your data.

Then follow this article that explains the procedure in great detail
and screenshots:
[How to Run a Startup Repair in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html).

In case of difficulties in following the article, find perhaps a friend
that can help.

If this happens again, you should investigate what causes the problem.
If the disk is not new, this might be a warning for the future.

Comment: Yes, it is, In this case the problem is much more serious than just the bootloader. I suggest now to [Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html). Even if it succeeds, you will need to do some verification afterward to find out why it happened.